# How do I choose: ini or registry?

Tags: c#

What is the difference may be in the possession of the settings in the .Ini file and stored in the system registry? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: I hope this article can help you understanding differences: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/26/6523907.aspx

Comment: Too broad. Is this settings for a computer, or for a user on a computer. PS I'd use xml config before I used ini anyay, and after many trials an tribulations the registry only if there was no other option.

Answer (score 2):

INI files were a Windows version 3.x artifact.  Windows contains heavy appcompat for them in order to allow Windows 3.x programs to still execute on modern Windows versions.  This appcompat is *extraordinary* expensive, reading a single setting from an .ini file costs 50 milliseconds.

There is also a very serious problem with text encoding, Windows can only assume that the .ini file text was encoded in a legacy code page, it assumes the default system code page.  With the significant problem that your .ini file content turns into garbage when it contains non-ASCII text and runs on another machine that's not close to yours.  Very hard to troubleshoot, next to impossible to fix.

Do **not** use INI files.

Comment: I think your answer only applies to the Windows GetPrivateProfileX functions. A custom ini reader implementation doesn't necessarily suffer from those problems.

Comment: Well, sure, that's what everybody uses.

Answer (score 0):

Refering to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9610086/1289469 from [esnyder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669843/esnyder):

> The registry is designed for persistent data storage with fast performance. Writing to and reading from the registry is safe. While a
>   "corrupted registry" is certainly one of those on-going pseudo-myths,
>   storing data in the registry doesn't necessarily "make all the
>   computers explode all of the things." There is generally something
>   very, VERY wrong if you're having registry issues today. It isn't only
>   Windows that uses a registry - you can also check into Gnome's gconf.
>   Mac uses a Property List (I think? I'm not a big Mac person....) and
>   there are many other "registry-like" mechanisms.

Comment: Seen way too many people trip up, and end up with a registry issue. Virtualisation, security, different windows versions and the ever popular run as admin, to dismiss the issues so easily. Certainly a competency issue, but as soon as you say use the registry, you've got to think through consequences and deal with them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of settings you want to store, and what they're used for, but to answer quickly:

If you want to store settings that can be easily edited by the the user, you can store them in a file (but not in a `ini`, `xml` files are far better for that),

if you want to store settings that shouldn't be visible or edited by the standard user, store them in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Well the registry provides configuration/settings per user/local machine etc. where the ini file doest not. Although you can store the ini file in appdata for the current user. The pros of having an ini file is that it is easy configurable in comparison of using regedit to edit the registry. I would say it depends on what type of information you want to store.

Comment: Why everyone say about xml? Why is it better than ini?

Comment: @MaximDroy Roberto Conte Rosito gave you a link in the commentes that explains why

Comment: In the .Net world the app.config has really replaced the ini file. Why everyone say xml, it is easy to serialize/deserialize xml to a class and you can work with strongly types. Also, Xml provides a more flexible markup than just your standard ini structure.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use .ini or registry? Maybe app.config is a better choice. It also depends on the type of settings you want to save.

Cons of Registry: 
* You have to remove saved settings when uninstalling the program. 
* It is not that easy to move settings to another machine.

Pros of Registry:
* Easier to have per-user settings.
* When saving an .ini-file in Program Files usually only administrator can edit it.
* Other application can access the settings saved in registry.